# How to make a request asynchronously in c# (xamarin)?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asynchronous, xamarin

I used to work with browser-based applications. for example Angular simple repository.

```
function getSomeData(params) {
        ...
        return $http({
            url: conf.urlDev + 'some/rest-url',
            method: "GET",
            params: params,
            cache: true
        }).then(getDataComplete);

        function getDataComplete(response) {

            return response.data;
        }
    }
```

How it will look the same in c# (XAMARIN for example)? 
i try :

```
 public class BaseClient 
{
    protected Http _client = null;
    protected string _urlObj;
    protected string _basePath;

    public BaseClient ()
    {
        _client = new Http(new HttpClientHandler());
    }

    public string Path
    {
        set
        {
            _urlObj = value;
        }
    }

    public async Task<Result<IList<T>>>getList<T>(Dictionary<string,object> parametrs = null)
    {
        if (parametrs != null)
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValue in parametrs)
            {
                _urlObj = _urlObj.SetQueryParam(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
            }
        }

        var response = await _client.GetAsync(_urlObj.ToString());

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return new Result<IList<T>>()
            {
                Success = true,
                Value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<T>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
            };
        }
        else
        {
            var error = new Result<IList<T>>()
            {
                Error = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                Message = response.ReasonPhrase,
                Success = false
            };

            return error;
        }
    }
```

in my service:

```
public async Task<IList<News>> GetAllNewsByParams(DateTime from,
                            string orderBy = "-published",
                            DateTime to = new DateTime(),
                            int page = 1, int category = 0)
    {
        _client.Path = _config.NewsPath;

        var  dict = new Dictionary<string, object> {
            {"from", from.ToString("s")},
            {"order_by", orderBy.ToString()},
            {"to", to.ToString("s")},
            {"page", page.ToString()}
        };

        if (category != 0)
        {
            dict.Add("category", category.ToString());
        }

        var res = await _client.getList<News>(dict);

        return res.Value;
    }
```

and im ny viewmodel

```
foreach (var item in await _newsService.GetAllNewsByParams(
                                         _To,
                                         _OrderBy,
                                         _From, _Page,
            selectedTag == null ? _SeletedNewsTagId : selectedTag.Id))
        {
            NewsList.Add(item);
        }
```

Is his query  executed synchronously ?
How do I make it an asynchronous?

Comment: If by asynchronous you mean *do not occupy a thread while waiting for a response*, then yes, your operation is purely asynchronous.

Comment: that is, there should not be .then({})?

Comment: `async`/`await` are an abstraction over call-back based asynchronous operations : you may see your `then` call-back as simply everything under the `await` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would really encourage you to use RestSharp, it really simplifies making HTTP requests and deserialise them. Add a [RestSharp nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable/) to your project. Here is how your code will look like using RestSharp.

```
public class BaseClient
{
    protected IRestClient _client = null;
    protected string _urlObj;
    protected string _basePath;

    public BaseClient()
    {
        _client = new RestClient();
    }

    public async Task<Result<IList<T>>> GetList<T>(string path, Dictionary<string, object> parametrs = null)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(path, Method.GET);
        if (parametrs != null)
        {
            foreach (var keyValue in parametrs)
            {
                request.AddQueryParameter(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
            }
        }

        var response = await _client.Execute<List<T>>(request);

        if (response.IsSuccess)
        {
            return new Result<IList<T>>()
            {
                Success = true,
                Value = response.Data
            };
        }
        else
        {
            var error = new Result<IList<T>>()
            {
                Error = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                Message = response.StatusDescription,
                Success = false
            };

            return error;
        }
    }
}
```

In  your service

```
public async Task<IList<News>> GetAllNewsByParams(DateTime from,
                        string orderBy = "-published",
                        DateTime to = new DateTime(),
                        int page = 1, int category = 0)
    {

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                        {"from", from.ToString("s")},
                        {"order_by", orderBy.ToString()},
                        {"to", to.ToString("s")},
                        {"page", page.ToString()}
                    };

        if (category != 0)
        {
            dict.Add("category", category.ToString());
        }

        var res = await _client.GetList<News>(_config.NewsPath, dict);

        return res.Value;
    }
```

And in your viewmodel

```
var news = await _newsService.GetAllNewsByParams(
                                     _To,
                                     _OrderBy,
                                     _From, _Page,
            selectedTag == null ? _SeletedNewsTagId : selectedTag.Id);
foreach (var item in news)
{
    NewsList.Add(item);
}
```

This will be 100% asynchronous.